# Algorithm to determine when to display points on a line graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, dhtmlx

I have a system that collects statistics from servers for every 5 minutes and displays a line  graph using dhtmlxChart as shown below. I want to add points to the graph when there are significant change of the trend in the statistics, for example when the line graph looks like saw teeth from 00:00 to 06:00 in the image below, the graph will display square points at the periodical high and low values. As you can see, my existing algorithm does not work well.

```
interate over each point:
   if last visible point not defined then:
      set current point as visible
      store current point as last visible point
   else:
      compare absolute difference between last visible point and current point
      if difference exceeds threshold or current point is the last point then:
         set current point as visible
         store current point as last visible point
```

What would be a correct algorithm to determine the visible points in the line graph?

[image: Graph]

Comment: Maybe you could set points at the local optimum(s). For each measure, check that the 2 measures around are both greater or smaller.

Comment: Aren't you just looking for changes in the sign of the slope ? You can consider all sections of the signal that are monotonous, and add a point at the end of a sufficiently high section.

Comment: How do you define "trend in the statistics"? Would the distance to a linear regression be a good measure? I.e. try to predict where a point should lie, given the last n points, and make it visible if it's far away from this prediction. However, the maxima in the saw-tooths won't be visible because they conform to the statistics (you could enable both the changed and previous point).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to add points, but you can redraw the chart using updated data source.
Look at the samples from [this theme](http://forum.dhtmlx.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=37671)

You can use your "line" chart type